# Push a local git branch to remote server for the first time

Tags: git

I have used git for a long while now at various places of work but never had to set a project up to use git and I'm struggling to understand how, and execute successfully...

I have a local folder which is a git repo:

```
c:\myDir\MyProject
```

I have a Linux server(with git installed) where I want push the local repo/site to, but I'm unsure how to create the bridge between them.

I read that on my server I need to go into a dir that will hold the repo and do

```
git init --bare
```

But then what? How do I create the bridge to push from local and pull from remote?

I've tried (from local):

```
git remote add origin ssh://myUrl.com
```

but then `git push origin master` gives `fatal: No path supplied` which I know is because I set it up wrongly

Can anyone offer basic direction so I can get started?

Comment: If your (bare) repository is at `/home/you/something.git`, then the URL you should use is `you@yourserver:something.git`

Comment: But when i do `git init --bare` all it does is add files (config, description, Head) and some directories (hooks, info, objects, refs) to the folder, doesn't create anything named `****.git`

Comment: You have to run `git init --bare` inside a folder named `something.git`

Comment: so I actually have to create a dir named `****.git` and then run `git init --bare` inside it? That is not documented anywhere that I can find - I'm not saying it's wrong, just that git set up might not be as well documented as it might/should be

Comment: It actually is documented. `git init` by default always runs in the current directory. The `--bare` option even explicitly mentions that it defaults to the current working directory. And no, you technically don’t have to create a folder ending with `.git`. You can use any folder, but the `.git` suffix is a convention to make it clear that this is a (bare) repository.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the remote, instead of just naming the server, you have to provide the full path on the server to the folder that contains the Git repository, i.e. the folder inside which you did the `git init --bare` (e.g. `/path/to/git-repo`)

```
git remote add origin user@example.com:/path/to/git-repo
```